# How to show toast overlaying status bar?

Tags: android, android-view, android-toast

I know to set the location at which the toast should appear on the screen with setGravity. But when i set toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0). It still inside the content view. Its possible to show the toast over content view/on status bar?

Comment: have a look in to this lib may helps you https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Comment: maybe you can hide bar before toast show. after you can show bar again

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible and you shouldn't even try to do that. You can hide status bar using immersive mode and then you could display toasts wherever you want on screen, since your activity will be fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

1. use reflect get the Toast's WindowManager.LayoutParams
2. add this flag WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN to "flags",make the Toast's Window fill the Screen.[WindowManager.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html)

   > Window flag: place the window within the entire screen, ignoring decorations around the border (such as the status bar).
3. there you go~